# Import not working with babel and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I try to start a new project with webpack and babel.
I can transpire my code es2015 and es6.

But i have a trouble with my import.
When i try to import function,var, or object i have this error :

## Error

#### with Chrome

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

#### with Mozilla

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Can you tell me what's wrong ?

## This is my Structure

- index.html
- package.json
- node_modules
- webpack.config.js
- assets

  - dist

    - bundle.js
  - js

    - app.js
    - test.js

## Webpack file

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './assets/js/app.js',
    watch: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    }
                },
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

## Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "svg-wipe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "webpack": "^4.18.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

## test.js

```js
function myImport(m) {
    return console.log(m);
}
export default myImport;
```

## app.js

```js
import myImport from './test'

myImport('hello i m imported function !');
```

## in my index.html

```html
<script src="./assets/js/app.js" ></script>
```

#### Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your output bundle.

```html
<script src="./assets/dist/bundle.js" ></script>
```